# Why SingleColumnValueFilter do not returns true answer on < and > operator?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Hi I am new to hbase and in phase of learning it. 
I created a table using hbase shell and put values into that table uing shell. 
But now when i want to get thos values using some filter like this:

```
HTable table = new HTable(conf, "test");

        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
        SingleColumnValueFilter colValFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("col"), Bytes.toBytes("age")
                , CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("118")));
        colValFilter.setFilterIfMissing(false);
        filters.add(colValFilter); 
        FilterList fl = new FilterList( FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL, filters);

        Scan s = new Scan();
        s.setFilter(fl);
        ResultScanner ss = table.getScanner(s);
        JSONArray arr=new JSONArray();
        for(Result r:ss){
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            for(KeyValue kv : r.raw()){

                String column=new String(kv.getQualifier());
                String value=new String(kv.getValue());
                obj.accumulate(column, value);

            }
            arr.put(obj);
        }
```

Now when i run this program i get different results. Like i get users whose age are less than 118 but still they get displayed.

**My Question:**

Why SingleColumnValueFilter do this?
Any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your column name really age or AGE ? HBase can be annoying if you didn't quote your column names during the creation ...

Comment: Yeah i am sure its age not AGE or Age or aGe.

Comment: I put value into table using hbase shell command lke: put 'test','r1','col:age','19'   Was this a valid way?

Comment: do you store the age value in hbase using string-bytes or using integer-bytes? because Bytes.toBytes("118") suggest that you compare the string value with binary comparator with operation greater, that will be executed lexicographicly

Comment: i dont knw how its stored. i stored it from hbase shell like put 'test','r1','col:age','19' . now its stored as String bytes or integer bytes?

Answer (score 1):

If you put data from hbase shell like `put 'test','r1','col:age','19'` it will be stored as String-bytes so when you compare it with > on BinaryComparator, it will compare lexicographicly and return any string that starts with character > than '1'

you should put it `put 'test','r1','col:age','\x13'` (hexadecimal value) if you want to put it as integer-bytes

Comment: What if i am putting integer values from java program using hbase client? Then how should i out values? Bytes.toBytes("118") or Bytes.toBytes(118)??

Comment: Bytes.toBytes(118) or to be accurate Bytes.toBytes((int)118)